# Getting the value of form select input returns "undefined"

Tags: jquery, html, forms, html-select

I have this html form code:

```
<form>
    <select id="sex" name="sex" onchange="alert($('#sex').val())">
        <option value="0">Male</option>
        <option value="1">Female</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Maybe I use the jquery syntax to retrieve the value incorrectly, but when the select is changed, a message box show up with message "undefined". I expect the result will be either 0 or 1, or at least "Male" or "Female". Not "undefined". What have I done wrong?

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: its working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/02etbob9/)

Comment: Are you sure you added jquery lib to your code

Comment: Have you added jQuery library ?

Comment: I have. I have another codes using jquery on other parts of the page and it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, for you :

http://jsfiddle.net/jm7uo5g0/

You need to add :selected after your #sex, in your $ selector :).

Like so :

```
<form>
    <select id="sex" name="sex" onchange="alert($('#sex :selected').val())">
        <option value="0">Male</option>
        <option value="1">Female</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And do not forget to add the Jquery file ;).

Comment: This solution works for me. I've tried this kind of solution before, but I didn't add space between "#sex" and ":selected". Never know that it's necessary. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

you can try this also

```
    onchange="alert(this.value)"
```

Comment: Thank you for giving alternative solution! :)

Answer (score 4):

Most probably, you are loading jQuery library at the end of the page. Either include the source before form declaration or use `this.value` as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Turns out I just need to add ":selected" after the id. Before, I've tried using "#sex:selected" but it won't work, before I didn't add extra space after "#sex".

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery library at the end. Their functions wont be accessible. If you see such error , there is surity that Library is included at the wrong place.

Best tip : Use/include jquery library in `<head>`